# Is the "self" argument of methods somehow protected?

Tags: python, multithreading, self

#### Edit:

My confusion has been cleared, thank you. 
Instead of retreading my confusion of a very simple concept buried in the complexity of threading and multiprocess, I will just state the source of my confusion, and the simple answer to it.
**I thought:** `self` was created BY `__init__()`, so that self is INSIDE the scope of `__init__()`. 
 **In reality**: `self` was created before the calling of `__init__()` and was created in the 'parent' scope of `__init__()`. So, `self` is actually a variable passed to `__init__()`. In conclusion, `self` is not protected and it is not special in anyway.

the code I posted below is a study in variable scoping involving threads ran by another process. while it is not related to the question anymore, it does challenge your understanding of python scoping a bit at the part: `self=10 # comment out this assignment and see what happens` in `def thread_WITHOUT_SelfPassedToIt():`. Thanks again.

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

class exe_classBased(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.aaa = 'aaa'

        self = 10


    def run(self):

        print(
            '===================================================\n'
            '<Round 0> self is NOT alterred in the scope of run()\n'
            '==================================================='
        )

        print('self in the start of run() ==>',type(self))

        def thread_WITHOUT_SelfPassedToIt():
            try:
                print('in a thread WITHOUT self passed to it, self==>', type(self))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            try:
                print('self.aaa==',self.aaa)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

            self=10 # comment out this assignment and see what happens
            

        def thread_WITH_SelfPassedToIt(self):
            print('in a thread WITH self passed to it, self==>', type(self))
            try:
                print('self.aaa==',self.aaa)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        t = threading.Thread(
            target=thread_WITHOUT_SelfPassedToIt,
            daemon=1,
        )
        t.start()

        t = threading.Thread(
            target=thread_WITH_SelfPassedToIt,
            args=(self,),
            daemon=1,
        )
        t.start()

        print(
            '===================================================\n'
            '<Round 1> self is ALTERRED in the scope of run()\n'
            '==================================================='
        )

        self=10


        print('in the immidiate start of run() after self=10, self==>', type(self))

        def thread_WITHOUT_SelfPassedToIt1():
            nonlocal self
            try:
                print('in a thread WITHOUT self passed to it, self==>', type(self))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

            self=11

        def thread_WITH_SelfPassedToIt1(self):
            print('in a thread WITH self passed to it, self==', self)
            try:
                print('self.aaa==', self.aaa)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        t = threading.Thread(
            target=thread_WITHOUT_SelfPassedToIt1,
            daemon=1,
        )
        t.start()

        sleep(1)
        # give the thread_WITHOUT_SelfPassedToIt enough time to have self=11 excecuted

        t = threading.Thread(
            target=thread_WITH_SelfPassedToIt1,
            args=(self,),
            daemon=1,
        )
        t.start()

        sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    e = exe_classBased()
    e.daemon = 1
    e.start()
    sleep(5)

'''
output:
===================================================
<Round 0> self is NOT alterred in the scope of run()
===================================================
self in the start of run() ==> <class '__mp_main__.exe_classBased'>
local variable 'self' referenced before assignment
local variable 'self' referenced before assignment
in a thread WITH self passed to it, self==> <class '__mp_main__.exe_classBased'>
self.aaa== aaa
===================================================
<Round 1> self is ALTERRED in the scope of run()
===================================================
in the immidiate start of run() after self=10, self==> <class 'int'>
in a thread WITHOUT self passed to it, self==> <class 'int'>
in a thread WITH self passed to it, self== 11
'int' object has no attribute 'aaa'
'''
```

Comment: If I make a variable named `x` and store a list in it like `x = [1, 2, 3]` and then afterwards I do `x = 6`, would you expect the list to "blow up"?

Comment: but the "self" in a multiprocessing class just inherited everything from multiprocess and it should hold many important information for the OS to start a process for it, right? in the subsequent threads, which run after the __init__, self reemerges as the real self.

Answer (score 3):

`self` is a local variable in that function. Reassigning it doesn't have any effect on the rest of the program. It's no different from assigning a parameter variable in some other function, e.g.

```
def add1(x):
    y = x + 1
    x = 10
    return y

foo = 3
bar = add1(foo)
print(foo)
```

This will print `3`, not `10`, because the assignment was local to `add1`.

Comment: I think I found the kink in my head now, this is a pure variable scoping problem. I somehow just somehow assumed self was first created in the init(). In reality, self is created before init, and it is created in a broader scope, and then it is passed to the init() method just like other functions and arguments.

Comment: Yeah, you seemed to think that the `__init__` method does a `return self` at the end, and that's what gets returned when you create the new object.

Answer (score 3):

With `self = 10` you are just resigning your local pointer to the current class instance to something else. Basically you loose the reference to "yourself", but just that.

To mutate `self`, you need to change some of it's attributes:

```
self.foo = bar
```

This modifies the same object `self` that was passed as parameter.

Comment: what happens inside the threads functions then? some "self' retrained their class instance status, some "self" degraded into an int.

Comment: The functions executed by `threading.Thread` don't have a reference to the `self` defined in the `run` method.
The two `local variable 'self' referenced before assignment` errors you see are caused by the first two print statements.

Comment: Overall, there is only one instance of `exe_classBased` which is created on the main method in `e = exe_classBased()`. Everything else are just references to that object. Taking one reference and pointing it to something else (in this case a `10`) doesn't change the object itself neither other references to it.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/1649846) answer to another question on a similar topic has some good information

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, strangely enough, I have very firm grasp of "reference passing" and "scoping". it is a mental "kink" that lead to the confusion. but still, please try this: delete `self=10` in the `thread_WITHOUT_SelfPassedToIt()` function definition, and run the code, the thread clearly has the reference from `self`, but this `self` seem to come from the `run()`'s scope.

Comment: PyCharm won't even highlight the `self` in the thread function definition, even though it is pointing to the class. Interestingly enough, PyCharm not highlighting was the trigger of this question. (I am referring to the code with  `self=10` deleted in the `thread_WITHOUT_SelfPassedToIt() ` function definition

Comment: Oh I see the problem now, my bad. The functions executed in another thread do have a reference to the `self` passed in `run`.
**But**, in round 1 there is a `nonlocal self` in the beginning. This tells python that `self` references the global `self` (from the run method).
On the round 0 there is no such thing and python is doing something similar to _hoisting_ in javascript.  Since there is a assignment later in the method of a local var `self`, the reference to the _global_ `self` is lost in the whole function scope.

Answer (score 2):

The `self` variable will not point to the class object itself when used as assignee. Instead, it will rewrite the local variable `self`.

Try instead:

```
class B: # We create a class B
 b = None

b = B() # We instantiate B

class A:
 def __init__(self):
  self.__class__ = b.__class__ # Ugly but works

a = A() # We instantiate A
type(a) # What is it exactly?
<class '__main__.B'> # Magic!
```

Comment: `self` is not a  keyword, just a variable.